# Java Applets not working in IE9

Tags: java, image, windows-7, windows-vista, internet-explorer-9

Is there any script or code that solves this problem?

Simply I have an image player in my web site which does not work in IE9. I know there is a solution ([Java Applet Not Working (Blank) in IE9](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2011/02/java-applet-not-working-blank-in-ie9/)) which remove the problem, but if a user have not sufficient knowledge of how Windows works, or the web site is just play on outdoor screens, it need to be fixed with code by developer. Here is my website: http://www.interactivity.com.au/

Do you know any solution on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Since in a nutshell, the reason they're not working is that they're being blocked by a security feature, by definition there's no way for your applet to get around it. If there was, then it'd be a bug in the filter, and if such a way was found, you'd expect the filter to then be fixed to prevent it.

Add a link on your site to a set of instructions on how to fix the problem.

Comment: +1 all power to the user, and them deciding whether their own browser should run applets.

Comment: This version works fine: http://code.google.com/p/slideshow/downloads/detail?name=Slideshow-1.3.1.zip&can=2&q=